# Store text as a number in Excel

Tags: excel, export, xlsx

I'm trying to make a function that exports an XLSX file based on a template. I currently unzip the template file, go through all the XML files looking for the worksheets, and then do a global find-and-replace on the appropriate strings - `placeholder_1`, `placeholder_2` and so on.

This does work but when you save the Excel file with `placeholder_1` etc. it marks those cells as text cells, so in the output you get loads of "Number stored as string errors". One possible solution is to save them as numbers - `100001`, `100002`, etc. But that isn't very nice.

Another option would be to do that and then go into the worksheet XML and replace `10000` with `placeholder_` so I have "strings stored as numbers" which is what I want. But that means you can't easily edit the template in Excel.

So does anyone know a way of storing a normal number cell in an XLSX file that actually contains text rather than a number?

(Yes I know this is somewhat hacky. If I had more time I would do a proper XML parser and everything, but I don't.)

Comment: What is your programing language?

Comment: C++ but that isn't really relevant. I don't want to use any XLSX file writing APIs for a number of reasons. Unless there is a really good easy to use one that does what I want, but I didn't find any in my search.

Comment: Timmmm: OpenTBS is a PHP tool that makes exactly what you ask for: it takes an XSLX template (made with Ms Excel or whatever) and it replaces placeholders with data using the technique of templates. See the demo http://www.tinybutstrong.com/tools.php It includes a feature to makes the cell type to fit to what you expect.

Comment: That is PHP (ugh) and also does the whole XML-parsing thing which I am trying to avoid. It's the right way to do it but it's also a lot more work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the XML file corresponding the the worksheet,
a cell is an entity like this:

```
<c r="A2" t="n">
    <v>18.999</v>
</v>
```

- Attribut `r` is the address of the cell in the worksheet.
- Attribut `t` type of the value stored by the cell (n=numeric, s=string, b=boolean), 'n' is the default value..
- Entity `<v>` contains the unformatted value in case of numeric or boolean.
  But, in case of a string, `<v>` contains the index value of the string stored in the file "xl/sharedStrings.xml" .

So your problem is to replace a combination such as :

**file "xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml" :**

```
<c r="A2" t="s">
    <v>29</v>
</c>
```

**file "xl/sharedStrings.xml" :**

```
<sst>
  ...
  <si><t>placeholder_1</t></si> // 29th entity
  ...
</sst>
```

with :

**file "xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml" :**

```
<c r="A2" t="n">
    <v>100001</v>
</c>
```

So in order to change the placeholder and the cell type, you have to :

1. Search into `"sharedStrings.xml"` for the index of entity `<si>` where is placed your placeholder (the value of the index is not explicit in `"sharedStrings.xml"` ).
2. Search into `"sheet1.xml"` for the `<v>` entity that contains this index.
3. Replace the value of this `<v>` entity with the unformatted numerical value.
4. Replace the attribute of its parent `<c>` entity with `"n"` (or delete attribute `t="s"`).

The good news are :

- You can leave unused shared string in `"xl/sharedStrings.xml"`, this will not make an error.
- You can apply a number format to your cell while it contains the string value `placeholder_1`. This number format will be kept and applied to the number when you'll change the cell type.

If you have the pleasure to work with PHP, there is a nice library call [OpenTBS](http://tinybutstrong.com/tools.php) that provides the feature of replacing textual placeholders in Excel worksheets and change the cell type if needed. OpenTBS is a plug-in for the TinyButStrong template engine for working with Ms Office and LibreOffice.

Comment: Figured as much. Useful info though for the wanderers of the web, cheers.